# How to troubleshoot schedulix connection failure

Tags: ubuntu

I have compiled and installed schedulix successfully on ubuntu, starting and stopping server works as expected but I can't connect to it using the username and password I specified.

Connection fails with below error:

```
schedulix@db1:~$ sdmsh --host localhost --port 2506 --user schedulix --pass mypassword
Connect Error: 02110192350, Invalid username or password
```

I don't see any errors in the logs and I don't know even how to reset that password.

Any help with troubleshooting this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer for above question from the schedulix email group, thanks to Dieter Stubler and Ronald Jeninga

Basically schedulix server comes with a default account where user is SYSTEM and password is G0H0me (0 is zero).

Password can be changed by modifying it in the server.conf and restarting the server, relevant section from server.conf can be found below:

```
#
# SysPasswd: The password of user SYSTEM
#
SysPasswd=G0H0ME
```